# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "extern "C" what is this error?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr, cimg, language-interoperability

i was trying to wrap cimg library inside c++/clr and when i try to build it i get a bunch of Link errors.

```
 Error  20  error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0002AC) "extern "C" int __stdcall DestroyWindow(struct HWND__ *)" (?DestroyWindow@@$$J14YGHPAUHWND__@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall cimg_library::CImgDisplay::_desinit_fullscreen(void)" (?_desinit_fullscreen@CImgDisplay@cimg_library@@$$FQAEXXZ)   c:\Users\serakpc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CimgWrapper\CimgWrapperCLI\Stdafx.obj    CimgWrapperCLI
```

source code in Stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "cimgheader\CImg.h"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just including the header isn't enough. If you have a static compiled library, you need to include it in your solution so the linker will be able to find the binary code and produce an executable. If you have source code of the library, you need to include it in the solution and compile it with your own code.

Comment: ya that was a good idea but the problem is it doesnt have an external source code the implementation is in the one huge header file.... if u wanna check it out here is the link http://cimg.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @user1250098 you need either a source code (no matter if in header or in cpp file) to compile with or static binary library to link with or dynamic binary library to address at runtime. These are the only ways to address an external code.

Comment: ok i try it but it works fine in win32 project and that makes me crazy. i thought every native c++ worlds just fine in clr but it doesnt;